# What's in the buffer after HidD_GetInputReport() call?

Tags: winapi, usb, hid

After reading up on [HidD_GetInputReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I got confused as to what precisely is returned in the buffer.
Assuming we want to receive a payload of N bytes, MSDN says that we need a buffer of N+1 bytes, with first byte set to Report ID or zero if no ID is specified.

In both cases, once we return from HidD_GetInputReport(), will there be still Report ID prepending the data in the buffer? Or, in other words, should I start reading the payload from offset 0 or offset 1? And would it be the same for unspecified(zero) and specified(non-zero) Report ID?

Comment: What mode are you using whereby you need to parse the buffer manually? There are a suite of parser functions that will transform the buffer into a documented type for you.

Comment: I know that, unfortunately I'm working with a custom HID that specifies no standart usages, only allowing raw reports to be read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, first byte in [HidD_GetInputReport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidsdi/nf-hidsdi-hidd_getinputreport) buffer always contains reportId.
Description was a bit misleading. Now it is updated.

[HID spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/hid1_11.pdf) have optimization that says if report descriptor doesn't have reportIds then reportId byte is ommited when transferring data on the wire - to send less data. This is the case for example for keyboard and mouse in default "boot" mode. But Win32 API always have this byte prepended and you're just put zero there when not used.

Proper size for this buffer is in [HIDP_CAPS.InputReportByteLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidpi/ns-hidpi-_hidp_caps) returned from [HidP_GetCaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/hidpi/nf-hidpi-hidp_getcaps) call.